# is there a python way of listing all the properties

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm really new to python so I'm not 100% sure about the terminology. Tried googling but none of the answers i found work for my use case.

I've made some code to list out all my emails

```py
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)  # "6" refers to the index of the inbox folder

emails = inbox.Items

restricted_emails = emails.Restrict("@SQL=urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%SEDIT%'")

for email in restricted_emails:
    print(email.Subject)
    print(email.SentOn)
```

What I was wondering is there a way to list out all the different properties/attributes within email without me needing to look up the documentation.

something that will produce an output like

email.Subject
email.SentOn
email.To
email.Body

Ive tried

```py
>>> dir(email)
['_ApplyTypes_', '_FlagAsMethod', '_LazyAddAttr_', '_NewEnum', '_Release_', '__AttrToID__', '__LazyMap__', '__bool__', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__int__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_builtMethods_', '_enum_', '_find_dispatch_type_', '_get_good_object_', '_get_good_single_object_', '_lazydata_', '_make_method_', '_mapCachedItems_', '_oleobj_', '_olerepr_', '_print_details_', '_proc_', '_unicode_to_string_', '_username_', '_wrap_dispatch_']

>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmembers(email)
```

but i can't make sense of the outputs

Comment: I'd suggest using an ipython terminal. In IPython, if you have an object e.g., `x = 1`, which is an integer, you can do ``x?` to get the doctring for the object. If you do `x.` and press tab it will bring up all the attributes and methods of that object.

Comment: [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#dir) will list all attributes and methods of the object's class. The attributes starting with `_` or `__` are quasi-private attributes (you don't really get fully private attributes in Python), and are generally intended for use within the class itself rather than being accessed by the user. The attributes starting and ending with `__` are magic/dunder methods that often overload various operators or provided information for various Python built-in functions.

Answer (score 1):

The `dir()` function lists all attributes/properties of the object, see docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir). Usually, attributes that starts with `_` are either for internal use or class specific names, so you might want to filter those away, e.g.

```
[p for p in  dir(obj) if not x.startswith('_')]
```

In your case, it seems that there are no attributes found by `dir(email)`.